# Child Activity in Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-manifest

So I have two Activities. The main is called **Main**, and the child one is called **Child**. When a button is clicked in the main activity it triggers the following piece of code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, Child.class);
Main.this.startActivity(i);
```

That opens the **Child** activity.

As soon as I call **finish()** or press the back button within the child activity instead of going back to the main one, the app just closes. Can you give me a hint where the problem might be :(

*P.S.* By trial and error I found out that if edit *AndroidManifest.xml* and add

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

within the declaration of **Child** the back button and calling **finish()** behaves as expected: closes the child activity and brings the main into focus. The problem is that when I start typing in an **EditText** the screen starts flickering (rather bizzare). So I can't use it as a dialog. My main activity uses the camera, so that might be making problems. Although when the child activity is started, the **onPause** event is fired and it stops the camera until **onResume** is called.

Edit:

So I tried using **startActivityForResult** and added

```
Toast.makeText(this, "onPause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

to the **onPause** and a similar one to the **onResume** methods. When the Child returns **onResume** doesn't get triggered. I even overrided **onActivityResult** and even that doesn't get triggered. :( So bizarre...

**I think I found the problem but I can't solve it myself**

When the **Child** activity is activated, **onStop** and immediately after that **onDestroy** are invoked within the **Main** activity. But why?!?

Comment: Have you tried `startActivityForResult`?

Comment: I agree with Pentium10. If your child (Sub) activity should always go back to the Main, then startActivityForResult() should be used.

Comment: Well, I tried it with no luck :( Is it possible that I did something wrong with the onPause and onResume overrides?

When I press back or invoke finish() the screen blinks for a second and the home screen appears but my app is still running in the background...

Comment: Here are my overrides

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     try {
     preview.onPause();
     mGameThread.pause();
     } catch (Exception e) {
   onError(print(e));
  }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     try {
     preview.onResume();
     mGameThread.unpause();
     } catch (Exception e) {
   onError(print(e));
  }
    }

P.S. Don't know how to format it to show it nicer :(
preview is my camera preview, and gamethread is a thread that is painting over that preview

Comment: You should be able to edit your original question to better format the additional info.

Comment: Why is every other word of this question bold?  It sure makes it hard to read.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to do the following:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Child.class);
startActivityForResult(i);
```

(You only need Main.this if you are invoking this from an inner class).

When you want to exit the child activity:

```
setResult(Result.OK);
finish();
```

This should cause onActivityResult to be invoked in your Main class, followed by OnResume.

If that doesn't work, you might try putting break points or print statements in the various onX methods, to see which are being called.

Comment: Well, that's weird. onResume is never fired when I press finish() within my Child class. I used Toast to show notification every time onPause or onResume is triggered, and they do get triggered when I start up Main but onResume doesn't get invoked when Child returns :x

Comment: So you saw OnActivityResult called, but not onResume?  I'm not sure that showing toasts is a good way to debug this.  I've seen them have odd side effects.  You might be better off with log statements or using the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#opennewscreen what happens when you launch the new Activity is indeed different:
If the first Activity is still visible somehow (as you discovered, if it's shown as dialog for example), it will just receive `onPause()`; if it's not visible at all anymore, it will receive `onStop()` too.
But as the other said, if you're launching the second activity to get results from it, `startActivityForResults` seems more logical

(I'm new and learning formatting too, you may want to read the help by clicking on the orange question mark - use 4 spaces before code samples to indent them, apparently)