# Prevent an Activity from being killed by the OS while starting a child activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a main activity which calls a child one via

```
Intent I = new Intent(this, Child.class);
startActivityForResult(I, 0);
```

But as soon as **Child** becomes visible the main activity gets its **onStop** and immediately after that **onDestroy** method triggered. And as soon as I call **finish()** within the **Child** activity or press the back button, the **Child** activity closes and the home screen shows (instead of the main activity).

How can I prevent the main activity from being destroyed? :\

Comment: We need to see more of your code, this isn't sufficient, because this way your MainActivity shouldn't be destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you launch a child Activity from which you expect return data, you'll probably want to use `startActivityforResult` instead.

You may want to check this question: [[Child Activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063410/child-activity-in-android/3065187#3065187)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063410/child-activity-in-android/3065187#3065187) as it seems to be the same problem.

Edit:

As for what's happening here, you could place code in the `onStop()` and/or `onDestroy()` methods to investigate - at least a call to [`isFinishing()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing()) to check why the Activity is being destroyed.
You should also use adb logcat from your host machine to check the logcat in case it holds more information - and maybe use `Log.d()` (the result goes into logcat as well) instead of toasts to make sure you don't miss them.

Comment: Well, that particular question is mine as well :D I just reposted the follow-up one cuz back there I didn't know the reason this was happening and I wanted to make a clean version :)

But as you can see, I've used startActivityforResult ;)

Answer (score 0):

I used Dialog instead of an Activity and everything worked well so I'm leaving it like that.

Answer (score 0):

check  androidmanifest nohistory=true and that made the OS destroy the activity before the result. that might be one of the reason for your problem.